# Prototype cell labels showing nil in Table View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using storyboards for creating a tableview and using prototype cells.
prototype cell contains a textlabel

TableViewController :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";



Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
NSLog(@"cellIdentifier = %@",cell);
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[Cell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"cellIdentifier = %@",cell);

}
            cell.nameLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


return cell;
```

cell.h

```
@interface Cell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel* nameLabel;
```

I imported cell.h in viewcontroller.m .
I named the restorationID of prototype cell as 'Cell' and class of prototype cell as 'Cell' and  linked the textlabel in prototype cell to nameLabel.

Problem is :
`cell.nameLabel.text` always returns nil value even though `[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` returns a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try naming the CellIdentifier instead of restorationID.

CellIdentifier is a way to tag tableViewCells. This is so that uitableView can know which uitableviewcell to pull out when it needs to reuse it.

Comment: Thanks.. it worked.  I mistook restorationID to CellIdentifier.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have done this steps:

1. Define a new class for your custom cell, must be `UITableViewCell` type
2. Add an IBOutlet property for your label in the custom cell class
3. Establish a connection between the outlet property and the label
4. Set the class type of your custom cell by selecting the prototype cell and go in the `Identity Inspector`
5. Change the code to reference your custom cell type instead of UITableViewCell

In addition, you should use `CellIdentifier` instead of `RestorationID`.

Answer (score 0):

You should set cell's `ReuseIdentifier` instead of `RestorationID`. I'm curious that you didn't set `ReuseIdentifier` and got no crash :)

By the way, If you use a custom cell with xib, you should always register it to UITableView instance in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Cell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
```